# Tool for distributed HTTP benchmarking?

Tags: http, distributed, benchmarking

I would like to benchmark a website that our company is developing. It will consist of multiple web- and backend-servers.

To be able to properly simulate a large amount of request, I was thinking about using our dev machines (approx 15 Xp/Vista) and a few spare Red Hat servers as benchmarking clients.

Is there any tool that would let me set up these machines as slaves/clients, and then control them into performing a combined benchmark and get aggregated results?

The benchmark would consist of simulating a normal user logging in and surfing a few pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is a reference in this domain.
You will setup on JMeter as controller and as many slaves as you need for your load depending on available memory and cpu.

In you case it's better to use non gui testing
for better performances results.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to simulate simple requests, you could use [Apache’s `ab`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have used [grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) quite successfully for this.

You may also want to note that we had severe infrastructural problems going from the intranet through to the DMZ where the servers were located, and this is not uncommon. No matter how much we pushed, we couldn't punch through enough traffic (Some companies can have gigabit internet connections from their DMZ and outwards, but the stuff pointing inwards is quite often a totally different caliber)

On one project we ended up with a few pizza box pc's in the server hall.

Answer (score 1):

If load testing over many machines is necessary, take a look at [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/), a distributed load-testing tool written in Erlang. It's full-featured and will definitely scale across many machines.

Comment: I believe it does answer the question. How do you think it does not? I'm genuinely curious; I don't answer much on SO.

Comment: I might have flagged it during one of the reviews as the question is off-topic and it did not make a sense back then. But I believe majority votes from community recognize this as a valid answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification.